# How can I retrieve MySQL temporary tables meta data within a single connection in JDBC?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, temp-tables

And once again I have found an issue that I don't know how to fight with. Let's assume we have the following testing code:

```
private static final String CREATE_TEMPORARY_TABLE =
        "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T1 (\n" +
        "\tA FLOAT(4, 1),\n" +
        "\tB FLOAT(5, 2),\n" +
        "\tC FLOAT,\n" +
        "\tD INTEGER\n" +
        ") ENGINE = MEMORY;";

private final String[] SHOW_TABLE_TYPES = new String[] {
        //"TABLE",
        "VIEW", "SYSTEM TABLE", "GLOBAL TEMPORARY", "LOCAL TEMPORARY", "ALIAS", "SYNONYM"
};

private void createTemporaryTable(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(CREATE_TEMPORARY_TABLE);
    statement.execute();
    statement.close();
}

private void showTables(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    final ResultSet set = connection.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, null, SHOW_TABLE_TYPES);
    while ( set.next() ) {
        out.println(format("%s %s %s %s %s",
                set.getString("TABLE_CAT"),
                set.getString("TABLE_SCHEM"),
                set.getString("TABLE_NAME"),
                set.getString("TABLE_TYPE"),
                set.getString("REMARKS")
        ));
    }
    set.close();
}

@Override
public void test(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    createTemporaryTable(connection);
    showTables(connection);
}
```

Expected result is writing the `T1` table meta data into the `out` stream. But nothing happens, and it seems that `getTables()` does not take into account the temporary tables. Don't know how I can resolve it... Is a work-around there? Your help is really very appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL sometimes does not provide support even for stupid things. There is no solution for the issue. Closed.